# Flume NG FileChannel is very slow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, filechannel

I have been experimenting with flume ng (flume-ng-1.2.0+24.81-1~lucid) and have been comparing the performance of the memory channel and file channel.

Each event in my test system is 1KB in size and with my current configuration I am able to handle around 30,000 EPS using the memory channel. However, when using the file channel I am only able to handle around 1600 EPS.

On average I expect to receive an average of 2500 EPS on my production system and I would like to use to file channel to provide approximately 1 hours worth of event buffering in the case of sink failure (I am using a HDFS sink with a 1Gbps connection to the hadoop cluster).

This is my file channel configuration:

```
agent.channels.c1.checkpointDir = ~/.flume/file-channel/checkpoint
agent.channels.c1.dataDirs = ~/.flume/file-channel/data
agent.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 13107200
agent.channels.c1.checkpointInterval = 30000
agent.channels.c1.maxFileSize = 9216000000
agent.channels.c1.minimumRequiredSpace = 524288000
agent.channels.c1.capacity = 9000000
agent.channels.c1.keep-alive = 3
agent.channels.c1.write-timeout = 3
agent.channels.c1.checkpoint-timeout = 600
agent.channels.c1.use-log-replay-v1 = FALSE
agent.channels.c1.use-fast-replay = FALSE
```

The batch size for my HDFS sink has been set to 5000.

Can anyone make any recommendations as to how I can improve the performance of my file channel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.0 is *very* odd. The current release version is 1.3.1.

That said, trunk is 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT and ~may~ get a release at the end of June. I believe the FileChannel had some updates in that time so you may like to retest using a build of that.
(`mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` is your friend).

Secondly, have you considered pointing the checkpointDir and dataDirs at their own disks?